# How to handle UIImagePickerController overlay rotation in landscape?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

You cannot subclass UIImagePickerController, but surely there is clean(not saying obvious or easy) way to keep camera feed as background of `UIViewController` and just make `UIImagePickerController` overlay to rotate like  it would respond to `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` ?
I just want to UIImagePicker stay in its beloved portrait orientation, but I want rotate my UI buttons that I put into camera overlay. What I have now, is changing each element's orientation with `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()` so it always stays at the same place, but rotates around each center.
I downloaded Layar app and the somehow achieved it... camera feed stays and UI buttons rotates (like `UIViewController`'s style).

**edit**: I have to use iOS 5.1 and Xcode 4.2
**edit2:** for now I have this `int DIRECTION` and depending on what is the current orientation of the device I assign from 0 to 3, so I can decide with what angle to rotate all UI buttons. I do this inside `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` which is returning only YES for portrait and upside portrait.

Answer (score -1):

You have to put constraints on the buttons and picker view.

Use this link to study AutoLayout concept by [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)

Hope this will help but you have to go through it thoroughly.